# Reachability issue while refreshing

Tags: ios, swift, networking, reachability, reachability-swift

First my code

```
 func checkInternetConnection() {

    reachability.whenReachable = { _ in
            self.loadPost()
            self.checkNewMessages()
            self.slowView.frame.size.height = 0
            self.slowView.isHidden = true
            self.internetStatus.text = ""
            self.slowView.layer.zPosition = 0
    }
    reachability.whenUnreachable = { _ in
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        self.slowView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.1491314173, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        self.slowView.layer.zPosition = 1
        self.slowView.frame.size.height = 40
        self.slowView.isHidden = false
        self.internetStatus.text = "Keine Internetverbindung!"
        self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
        self.Indicator.stopAnimating()

    }
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.internetChanged(note:)), name: Notification.Name.reachabilityChanged, object: self.reachability)
    do {
        try self.reachability.startNotifier()
    }catch {
        print("error")
    }

}

@objc func internetChanged(note: Notification) {
    let reachability = note.object as! Reachability
    if reachability.connection != .none {
            self.slowView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3411764801, green: 0.6235294342, blue: 0.1686274558, alpha: 1)
            self.slowView.layer.zPosition = 1
            self.slowView.frame.size.height = 40
            self.slowView.isHidden = false
            self.internetStatus.text = "Mit dem Internet verbunden!"
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3 , execute: {
                self.slowView.layer.zPosition = 0
                self.slowView.frame.size.height = 0
            })

    } else {
        print("kein internet")
    }

}
```

I call the checkInternetConnection() method in viewDidLoad() and its works fine but as soon as I refresh my tableview it does not enter the reachability closure.

In handleRefresh() ( works fine for just reloading the posts) the checkInternetConnection() method is called but does not fire any code, the issue only appears while refreshing, not the initial loading.

I used this video for reference:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDZmz9IsB-8
Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

I think (but am not 100% sure) that the closures `whenReachable` and `whenUnreachable` are only called when the appropriate reachability change happens; in addition they might get called automatically when they are assigned. So no matter how often you call your `checkInternetConnection` the closures won't get re-executed unless the device goes offline/online.

To fix this I suggest to instead use the reachability flags:

```
if reachability.isReachable {
  // update view for reachable state
}
else {
  // update view for unreachable state
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks, it works better now. My issue now is that when as soon as i am connected again to the internet and I refresh, my app crashes (index out of range). This does not happen when I wait like 5 seconds until I refresh? I could work around this problem with delayed loading but I guess that wold be poorly done and not the best solution, any idea for solving this issue?

Comment: Well, find out where the invalid access takes place... that's a separate problem, not connected to your original question, so you should try to separate it and -- if needed -- create a new question.